# Get JointType from Body class Kinect

Tags: c#, kinect

I know in the old SDK, there was a `Skeleton` class and you can do something like

```
public void Compare(Skeleton skeleton) {
    var leftShoulderPosition = skeleton.Joints.Where(j => j.JointType == JointType.ShoulderLeft);
}
```

However, the new SDK came out and the `Skeleton` class is replaced by the `Body` class. Now, the code is throwing an error at `j.JointType`.

Is there a workaround for this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Microsoft Kinect SDK v2.0, you can get the `ShoulderLeft` joint (and, similarly, any other skeletal joint) as follows:

```
body.Joints[JointType.ShoulderLeft]
```

where `body` is an instance of the [`Body`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowspreview.kinect.body.aspx) class to which you refer.