# Kinect v1, and Kinect v2 classes alternatives

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, kinect, kinect-sdk

I have been debugging a lot of errors while converting a code that uses Kinect V1 classes, into Kinect V2 classes. As [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34832590/get-jointtype-from-body-class-kinect) stated, there are some changes.
So far I have managed to debug some classes like Skeleton into Body, but there are some missing parts with the Skeleon and AllFramesReadyEventsArgs:

```
private void KinectAllFramesReady(object sender, AllFramesReadyEventArgs e)
        {
            // Have we already been "shut down" by the user of this viewer, 
            // or has the SkeletonStream been disabled since this event was posted?
            if ((this.Kinect == null) || !((KinectSensor)sender).SkeletonStream.IsEnabled)// Error with Skeleton Stream
            {
                return;
            }

            bool haveSkeletonData = false;

            using (BodyFrame skeletonFrame = e.OpenSkeletonFrame())
            {
                if (skeletonFrame != null)
                {
                    if (this.skeletonCanvases == null)
                    {
                        this.CreateListOfSkeletonCanvases();
                    }

                    if ((this.skeletonData == null) || (this.skeletonData.Length != skeletonFrame.SkeletonArrayLength))// Error with SkeletonArrayLength
                    {
                        this.skeletonData = new Body[ skeletonFrame.SkeletonArrayLength];
                    }

                    skeletonFrame.CopySkeletonDataTo(this.skeletonData);// Error with Skeleton Frrame

                    haveSkeletonData = true;
                }
            }
```

I still have the Frame reader, what is the Kinect V2 alternative for it? 
I have the following code which is for Kinect V1:

```
protected override void OnKinectChanged(KinectSensor oldKinectSensor, KinectSensor newKinectSensor)
        {
            if (oldKinectSensor != null)
            {
                oldKinectSensor.AllFramesReady -= this.KinectAllFramesReady;
                this.HideAllSkeletons();
            }

            if (newKinectSensor != null && newKinectSensor.Status == KinectStatus.Connected)
            {
                newKinectSensor.AllFramesReady += this.KinectAllFramesReady;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

To replace the `OnKinectChanged` event, you can use the `IsAvailableChanged` event on the `KinectSensor` object.

Comment: Could you provide me with a proper code please? 
I changed it, but still there are some errors from `AllFrameReady`, plus, the `KinectStatus` error

Answer (score 0):

main difference is between  Skeleton Class in Kinect V1 and Body Class in kinect V2 But for developing kinectV2 with SDK2  you have to use MultiSourceFrameReader Class